# Multiple Base64 images on Html page and smooth loading

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64

Does someone know a technique to make asynchonous image parsing when multiple images are printed (base64) on a webpage ?

It causes Firefox to have small freeze on loading/parsing on a gaming machine (for more than 15 images 1.5MB), so I'm a bit worried of that.

Still I think giving an url and using a javascript async (lazy) image loading is better, if someone have some more informations tips, I'll be glad to hear it Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you put your images in base64 encoded elements ? This prevents caching by the browser.

Comment: Because they are stored, in DB as binary. 
There is a limited number of them and they are important for the business model of the Application, not just assets.
Maybe rendering on a file and then linking the file is a better solution ?
I already have a url to render them separately (no http caching with this solution).

Comment: If you have an url to render them, it's probable you can set up http caching (a trick is often to ensure the url changes when the content change, for example by including a hash of the content)

Comment: Yeah, nice trick including a bit of the content..
I have an url like "avh/intra/misc/binimage/T0RBM1pERTRNemcyTlRrNVptWmtPVEl6Wk...."

Comment: The Header answer (for rendered url) :
```Cache-Control: max-age=37739520, public
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 487273
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 12:15:51 GMT
Expires: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 17:15:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Pragma: public```

Comment: Headers for a normal image file :
```Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 12292
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 12:21:52 GMT
Etag: "3004-511a51fb73c3f"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=83
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2015 14:36:22 GMT```

But the browser doesn't cache image (the generated one) , in cause apache doesn't send directly the media files (so no mod expires) . I may be missing something here

Comment: Ok I just found https://annevankesteren.nl/2005/05/http-304,
I have to send myself the 304 code (silly of me), so 'il use your technique :)

Comment: UPDATE:
I just managed to make cache work on me url that generate images using ETag Header.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/intelligent-php-cache-control/

Comment: Don't forget to write a proper answer, if you manage to make that clear ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, there is no way to **control browser parsing speed with printed base64 images** (sended in html HTTP response). If you print a lot of images the browser will use more CPU to parse the webpage.

The solution if you have bin images is to **call them separately**, you will have to get an url to serve image data individually (no static files).

The problem with this is **making the browser cache working** : if not every time the page is loaded you will have to render every image on the page causing the webserver overheat.

Another solution would be to **cache image on the server side**, but still the client would have to download image every time consuming the webserver bandwidth.

**Browser cache can be activated with http cache-control** : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/intelligent-php-cache-control/

The best thing is to use cache-control, but also use cache on server side.

Of course this only apply for binary data, if you have image file just let your **webserver to server image file naturally**.